# Using "require" in ng-metadata

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to translate over some `angular` code that used `require: {}` in a `component` to get access to a parent component with `ng-metadata`.

In my `angular 1` code, it looked like this ...

```
angular.component('docsMenu', {
   // ...
   require: { '^^^container' }
});
```

I found I specifically had to use `^^^` to make it work right. I'm having trouble figuring out how to translate this over to `ng-metadata` though. The component structure is ...

```
<container>
--- <navigation>
--- <sidebar>
--- --- <docs-menu container="$container">
```

`<docs-menu>` needs to access the `container` to call a function sometimes.

The documentation for `ng-metadata`, [seen here](https://github.com/ngParty/ng-metadata/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) says ...

#### Previously if you wanted to achieve require:['myCmp','ngModel'] you had to use 3 decorators:

```
@Component({selector:'my-cmp',template:`Hey there`})
class MyCmp{
  constructor(@Inject('ngModel') @Host() @Self() private ngModel){}
}
```

from now on you have to use 3 decorators only if you wanna make it optional, otherwise it will throw error:

```
// OK
@Component({selector:'my-cmp',template:`Hey there`})
class MyCmp{
  constructor(@Inject('ngModel') @Self() private ngModel){}
}
```

for optional require:['myCmp','?ngModel']:

```
// OK
@Component({selector:'my-cmp',template:`Hey there`})
class MyCmp{
  constructor(@Inject('ngModel') @Self() @Optional() private ngModel){}
}
```

But trying `@Inject('^^^container') @Self private container: any' in the constructor doesn't seem to work.

Basically, there is a root component, `<container>`. It doesn't really do much. However, there is another component `<docs-menu>` that contains a menu system. I need the ability to call a `refresh` function on this component from another component in the system. The two components that must interact have nothing in common except that they are both somewhere inside the `<container>`. So previously, I was using `require: { '^^^container' }` in order to call upon the top level container, and then when it had a function called, it would actually trigger the right function on the `docs-menu` component.

Comment: Where did this `^^^container` come from? `^` and `^^` mean very specific things, they are not countable https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile . If `^^^container` is supposed to be grand-grand-parent, that's wrong. For `^^` it will likely be @SkipSelf.

Comment: To be honest, I can't remember why I used `^^^`. I just know that I kept trying things for hours, and that is what worked.

Comment: The layout is like this; https://plnkr.co/edit/FqNSJFS0vBmiejk4n80o?p=preview It's possible for whatever component gets rendered in `<content>` to need to call a function on `docs-menu`, and that's how I was accomplishing it.

Comment: Well, in this case the reason matters, because ^^^ doesn't seem to be valid require modifier in Angular (I would expect that it will throw an error). Any way, from here it looks like it should be ^^, or SkipSelf.

Comment: So I'd use ... `@Inject('^^container') @SkipSelf() private container: any`?

Comment: No, i meant @Inject('container') @SkipSelf() private container: any . My guess is that's how ng-metadata replicates A2 injector.

Comment: Thank you. I finally got it working correctly! Can you please post this as the official answer so I may award credit?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I don't use ng-metadata, but considering that it tries to replicate A2 decorators as close as possible, this was a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the desired `require` modifier is `^^` (parent controllers only), the counterpart in Angular 2 decorators is `SkipSelf` - and so in `ng-metadata`:

```
constructor(@Inject('container') @SkipSelf() private container){}
```